# Enabling/Disabling RequiredFieldValidator

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I have 2 combo box drop downs. On page load the 2nd drop down with validator are disabled. If the user selects any value from the first drop down I enable it. The 2nd drop down enables but the validator does not.

page load

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load 
    ComBox_GER2.Enabled = False            
    Valid_GER2.Enabled = False       
End Sub
```

Is fired ComBox_GER1.SelectedIndexChanged

```
If ComBox_GER1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        Else
            ComBox_GER2.Enabled = True
            Valid_GER2.Enabled = True
        End If
```

Comment: Have you tried using their Visible property? Are the ValidationGroups set properly? Do both controls get updated in the partial postback if you are using AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

in every Page_Load add

```
AjaxManager.AjaxSettings.AddAjaxSetting(ComBox_GER1,ComBox_GER2)
AjaxManager.AjaxSettings.AddAjaxSetting(ComBox_GER1,Valid_GER2)
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ValidatorEnable(ValidatorControlName,Boolean) javascript function](http://vijayraju-ourworld.blogspot.gr/2013/09/dynamically-enable-or-disable-required_24.html)

```
//Example:
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%= Valid_GER2.ClientID %>'), true);
```